# Downgrading Tomcat on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, tomcat6

I installed Tomcat 7 and it is giving me all sorts of fits :)
.jar files are missing and I have many error messages coming at me from different directions :)

As I understand it, deleting tomcat is not trivial due to the many paths it sets during installation.  Is there a recommended or safe way to just remove or disable tomcat 7, and install tomcat 6 on ubuntu?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I would like to do something like sudo apt-get remoce tomcat, but that didn't work :)  How can I look up the list of things I can call with the apt-get remove command? - Thanks!

Comment: Did you install it with "apt-get install tomcat"? if not, then apt won't know how to remove it.

Comment: A "sudo apt-cache search tomcat" on my 10.10 vm does not list tomcat 7 as in installable option for me.  Did you download tomcat 7 binaries from tomcat.apache.org?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package manager can only uninstall stuff that it has installed.

If you followed the Tomcat 7 install instructions, then it really should be as simple as reversing your changes.. but if you're not exactly sure what's been done, a fresh install of the OS may be a good idea.

Comment: A fresh install of the OS is not realistic.  Isn't there another wayto get this figured out? Hmmmm

Answer (score 1):

How did you make the installation ? Source ? Package ? If it was from a package you can see the provided files